# Lowercase transformed text appears in uppercase in form history

Tags: css

I need to transform form input text in lowercase. I have done this part by using text-transform property of css. But the problem comes when we fill form again and form data comes from form history as options for the input. Data coming from history shows two options for each option one in lowercase and the other in upper case eg AISHA ZAFAR and aisha zafar appears as the two options for the drop downs. Is it related to form submitting or something else.

This issue actually occurs when we on capslock and enter text. Although css converts it to lowercase for user but in form history I see two formatted strings for the text, one in lowercase and the other in uppercase.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has to do with browser caching. Why exactly do you need the input field in all lower case?

Comment: You are not really telling us much - is this .js, c# etc? Most languages have a .ToLower() function which you can attach... there is just not enough information to help you with this.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I had to make change to allow users to enter username only in lowercase and for that I used text-transform property of css and for server side I am using PHP. Its works fine for me. The issue comes when we see usernames(coming from cache) as options in the textboxes and for each user name I see two formatted usernames 1 in lowercase and the other in uppercase. This issue comes when we on capslock to enter username.

Answer (score 0):

may be is a browser caching, you can try disable autocomplete

```
<input type="text"  autocomplete=off  name="email"  style=" text-transform: lowercase;" >
```